# Filter based on paired-fields for grouped IDs

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to figure out a filter to identify ids for the following dataframe.

```
x <- data.frame("log_id" = c(16006,16006,16006,25109,25109,25109,25109,20506,20506),
                "status" = c(0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1), 
                "version" = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2),
                "date_time" = c(as.Date("2018-10-27 00:00:00"), as.Date("2019-01-06 00:00:00"),as.Date("2019-01-16 00:00:00"),
                                as.Date("2018-10-27 00:00:00"), as.Date("2017-01-06 00:00:00"), as.Date("2019-02-17 00:00:00"),
                                as.Date("2018-10-27 00:00:00"), as.Date("2019-01-12 00:00:00"),as.Date("2019-02-12 00:00:00")))
```

I need to identify ids such that date_time associated with higher version numbers, after having grouped by log_id, should be more recent that previous version numbers.

In other words, for each log_id, records with a higher version should have a datetime >= than the previous ones. I need to find log_id with events that fail this condition and record the specific "log_id".

I tried a dplyr solution based on group_by and do, with an ifelse, but couldn't manage to get the correct syntax.

```
solution <- x %>%
  select(log_id,
         status,
         version,
         date_time) %>%
  group_by(log_id) %>%
  {(ifelse(date_time[version== 1] < date_time[version!=  1], 0,1))} %>%
  arrange(log_id)
```

I am expecting to have results, stored in a vector, such that all problematic "log_id" are identified.

For this dataframe, the expected output is:

```
"incidented log_id = " "25109"
```

The reason being that log_id = 25109 has the date_time value ("2017-01-06 00:00:00") associated with its version=2 older than the date_time value ("2018-10-27 00:00:00") associated with its version=1.

Comment: Can you post the expected output for that data example?

Comment: Just clarified the expected output in the description. I am expecting to have the log_id 25109 since the value associated with version 2 (2017-01-06 00:00:00) is older than the value associated with version 1 (2018-10-27 00:00:00).

Comment: See if it is right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if the following does what you want.
It groups by `log_id` and then computes the differences between the `date_time` values. If the differences are less than zero, then the previous `date_time`'s are higher and just `filter` by that logical result.

The first version keeps entire rows where the next `date_time` is less than the previous one

```
x %>%
  group_by(log_id) %>%
  filter(c(0, diff(date_time)) < 0)
## A tibble: 2 x 4
## Groups:   log_id [1]
#  log_id status version date_time 
#   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <date>    
#1  25109      1       2 2017-01-06
#2  25109      1       4 2018-10-27
```

The second version returns the problematic `log_id`'s only.

```
x %>%
  group_by(log_id) %>%
  filter(c(0, diff(date_time)) < 0) %>%
  select(log_id) %>%
  unique()
## A tibble: 1 x 1
## Groups:   log_id [1]
#  log_id
#   <dbl>
#1  25109
```